# How to run X tasks on Y threads in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, multitasking, threadpoolexecutor

I want to meassure an average time of executing a task on 5 threads doing 100 tasks.

For time meassuring purposes I use `nanoTime()`

The task is calling one specific method, let's call it `foo();`
I don't create any additional classes.

In my code I create a task:

```
Runnable thExecute = new Runnable(){
  @Override
  public void run(){
    foo();
  }
};
```

And then I create a thread:

```
Thread th = new Thread(thExecute);
long start = System.nanoTime();
th.run();
long stop = System.nanoTime();
```

This would be great if I had the same number of tasks as threads. 
I tried to create arrays of threads and tasks:

```
Runnable[] thExecutes = new Runnable[100];
Thread[] ths = new Thread[5];
```

But now I don't know what to do next. I know they should be queued somehow and probably I should use `Executor` class. I use Java 6.

Edit: 
At first I didn't mean what I wrote. Now I know I want average time + highest time.

Comment: Have a look at the [Executor interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html)

Comment: You can use Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5) and then submit your 100 Runnables.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing to note: you should not expect precise results, if you measure performance by yourself. There are [tools](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) that do it for you, providing much more reliable results.

If you want to do it by yourself, use ExecutorService:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
long startTs = System.nanoTime();

List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for (Runnable r : runnables) {
    futures.add(service.submit(r));
}
for (Future f : futures) { 
    f.get(); 
}

long durationNs = System.nanoTime() - startTs;
```

And again: since you are measuring nanoseconds, I strongly encourage you to avoid manual measurements, because there are many factors that will spoil the results: no warmup, setup expenses, etc.

**Update**: to measure execution time of every task, you can submit `Callable<Long>` instead of `Runnable`

```
public long call() {
    long startTs = System.nanoTime();
    // do the task
    return System.nanoTime() - startTs;
}
```

Now Future will return the execution time, you can print it or gather in a list:

```
for (Future<Long> f : futures) {
    long spentTime = f.get();
}
```

Comment: I changed my question a little. Can I put startTs and stopTs between f.get(); to get time of one task?

Comment: @Kamil then it will be better to use Callable instead, that will return the execution time, see the updated answer

Comment: so, where do I use Collable and where do I call call()?

Comment: You change your `thExecute` as a `Callable`instead of `Runnable` and override the `call`method in it instead of the `run` method.

Comment: @Kamil Method #call will be executed automatically be ExecutorService, just like method #run in Runnable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [Executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html):

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
long start = System.nanoTime();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    executorService.submit(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            foo();
        }
    });
}
try {
    // set whatever timeout value you want (must be > than the execution time)
    executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES); 
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
long stop = System.nanoTime();
```

It will create an executor with a fix size of  5 threads then push 100 task to teh executor. The executor will dispatch the task on each thread.

Answer (score 0):

I always like to use `ThreadPoolExecutor`

[ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)  would be more effective if you have customized many or all of below parameters preferably : `BlockingQueu`e Size (control unbounded queue size) , `ThreadFactory` for custom thread life cycle management & `RejectedExecutionHandler` to handle rejected tasks .

```
ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, 
               int maximumPoolSize, 
               long keepAliveTime, 
               TimeUnit unit, 
               BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, 
               ThreadFactory threadFactory,
               RejectedExecutionHandler handler)
```

Sample code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy;

class SimpleThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
   String name;
   static int threadNo = 0;

   public SimpleThreadFactory (String name){
       this.name = name;
   }
   public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
     ++threadNo;
     System.out.println("thread no:"+threadNo);
     return new Thread(r,name+":"+threadNo );
   }
   public static void main(String args[]){
        SimpleThreadFactory factory = new SimpleThreadFactory("Factory Thread");
        final ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(5,20,10,TimeUnit.SECONDS,new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10),factory,new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy());
        for ( int i=0; i < 1000; i++){
            executor.submit(new Runnable(){
                 public void run(){
                   // Add t1 here
                    System.out.println("Thread Name in Runnable:"+Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " of "+ executor.getPoolSize() );
                   // print System.currentTimeMillies - t1 here
                 }
            });
        }
        executor.shutdown();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code simply does not run in a separate thread because of this

```
th.run();
```

you should call `start()` instead of `run()` to achieve multi-thread functionality

Comment: yup, there was start() but because I've been reading you shouldn't use run() it stuck in my mind and I typed here run() instead